# Why random.sample can't handle numpy arrays but random.choices can?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random

Python's `random` module has `random.choices` for sampling with replacement and `random.sample` for sampling without replacement. Although `random.choices` accepts a numpy array and returns a list of randomly selected elements with respect to the first dimension, `random.sample` raises

> TypeError: Population must be a sequence or set.  For dicts, use list(d).

On the other hand, `random.choices` will not accept sets, raising

> TypeError: 'set' object does not support indexing.

What I'm curious about is if this is an oversight or if there's an essential reason for restricting `random.sample` to sequences and sets while `random.choices` is restricted to objects supporting indexing, despite the functions having very similar purposes.

P.S. if anyone is wondering about how to sample an ndarray, `numpy.random.choice` samples 1darrays both with and without replacement, and higher-dimension arrays can be effectively sampled with respect to any dimension with advanced indexing where the indices for that dimension are generated with `numpy.random.choice`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`random.sample` tries to [check](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/random.py#L316) whether its argument is an instance of `collections.abc.Sequence` or `collections.abc.Set`. This is a much less reliable check than many people believe, since it only detects types that concretely inherit from those ABCs or that are explicitly registered. `numpy.ndarray` doesn't inherit from those classes and isn't registered.

Without the check, or if you explicitly do [`collections.abc.Sequence.register(numpy.ndarray)`](https://ideone.com/dhHoaf), `random.sample` handles `numpy.ndarray` fine.

Incidentally, `numpy.random.choice` with `replace=False` is absurdly inefficient, generating an [entire permutation](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.17.2/numpy/random/mtrand.pyx#L845) of the input just to take a small sample. It's a [longstanding issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/2764) that hasn't been fixed due to the fact that the natural fix would change the results for people using `seed`. As of NumPy 1.17, you should instead use the new Generator API:

```
rng = numpy.random.default_rng()
result = rng.choice(input, size=whatever, replace=False)
```

The Generator API is not bound by backward compatibility guarantees with the old API, so they were free to change the algorithm. If you're stuck on an old NumPy, then depending on the parameters, it is often faster to use `random.sample`, or to compute the sample manually, than to use `numpy.random.choice` with `replace=False`.